# How to search for both within filename (find) and file (grep) using a single line of code?

Tags: command-line, find, grep

I'm pretty sure I've done this in the past (and that an answer is out there somewhere), but can't remember right now.

I'm looking for a **one-liner** to search for (and return / echo) matches in both the **filename** and **file**.

---

*Probably the easiest would be to run `grep` and `find` separately after each other; but I'd prefer a one-liner...*

...*unless it were possible* with a **semicolon** (?) or other to run these tools sequentially.

---

I don't think the solution I'm after would involve piping | because, to borrow from ***set theory***, I'm interested in the ***union*** of the two sets A and B (**A ∪ B**), rather than their *<strike>intersection</strike>* (A ∩ B).

Comment: meta: should this question be migrated to a different SE site, e.g. **stackoverflow** or **superuser** ?

Answer (score 2):

You're right - you can use semicolon to run list of commands sequentially:

```
$ find . -name 'test'; grep test *
```

You can also group it to run as single command: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
find <here your starting string > -type f -exec grep -l <here place the part of file name> {} \;
```

Description of the above command:

`find snow -type f` -> find all files starting from snow.
`find .... -exec` -> for each item found, do the following command. Where you normally place the filename in you command, put {} .
`grep -l "String" something` -> returns the filename if string "String" is found in file something.

Credit:[dbasupport.com](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?3929-How-to-use-GREP-FIND-to-search-a-string-in-all-the-subdirectories-and-files)

Comment: To borrow from set theory, I'm interested in the **union** of the two sets A and B (A ∪ B), rather than their *intersection* (A ∩ B) -- as I tried to make clear in my question above...